# Why does the results of the bootstrapping methods differs if it is being used the same seed?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, random-seed, statistics-bootstrap

I want to generate 95% confidence intervals from the R2 of a linear model. While developing the code and using the same seed for both approaches, I figured it out that doing the bootstrap manually doesn't give me the same results as using the boot function from the boot package. I am wondering now if I am doing something wrong? or why is this happening?

On the other hand, in order to calculate the 95% CI I was trying to use the confint function, but I'm getting an error "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors". Any solution to avoid this error?

Here is a reproducible example to explain my concerns

```
#creating the dataframe
a <- rpois(n = 100, lambda = 10)
b <- rnorm(n = 100, mean = 5, sd = 1)
DF<- data.frame(a,b)

#bootstrapping manually
set.seed(123)
x=length(DF$a) 
B_manually<- data.frame(replicate(100, summary(lm(a~b, data = DF[sample(x, replace = T),]))$r.squared))
names(B_manually)[1]<- "r_squared"

#Bootstrapping using the function "Boot" from Boot library
set.seed(123)
library(boot)
B_boot <- boot(DF, function(data,indices)
  summary(lm(a~b, data[indices,]))$r.squared,R=100)

head(B_manually) == head(B_boot$t)
r_squared
1     FALSE
2     FALSE
3     FALSE
4     FALSE
5     FALSE
6     FALSE
#Why does the results of the manually vs boot function approach differs if I'm using the same seed?

# 2nd question (Using the confint function to determine the 95 CI gives me an error)
confint(B_manually$r_squared, level = 0.95, method = "quantile")
confint(B_boot$t, level = 0.95, method = "quantile")
#Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

#NOTE: I already used the boot.ci to determine the 95 confidence interval, as well as the 
#quantile function to determine the CI, but the results of these CI differs from each others
#and just wanted to compare with the confint function.
quantile(B_function$t, c(0.025,0.975))
boot.ci(B_function, index=1,type="perc")
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `boot` package does not use `replicate` with `sample` to generate the indices. Check the `importance.array` function under the [source code for boot](https://github.com/cran/boot/blob/master/R/bootfuns.q). It basically generates all the indices at one go. So there's no reason to assume that you will end up with the same indices or same result. Take a step back, the purpose of bootstrap is to use random sampling methods to obtain a estimate of your parameters, you should get similar estimates from different implementation of bootstrap.

For example, you can see the distribution of R^2 is very similar:

```
set.seed(111)
a <- rpois(n = 100, lambda = 10)
b <- rnorm(n = 100, mean = 5, sd = 1)
DF<- data.frame(a,b)

set.seed(123)
x=length(DF$a) 
B_manually<- data.frame(replicate(999, summary(lm(a~b, data = DF[sample(x, replace = T),]))$r.squared))

library(boot)
B_boot <- boot(DF, function(data,indices)
  summary(lm(a~b, data[indices,]))$r.squared,R=999)

par(mfrow=c(2,1))
hist(B_manually[,1],breaks=seq(0,0.4,0.01),main="dist of R2 manual")
hist(B_boot$t,breaks=seq(0,0.4,0.01),main="dist of R2 boot")
```

[image]

The function `confint` you are using, is meant for a `lm` object, and works on estimating a confidence interval for the **coefficient**, see [help page](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/confint). It takes the standard error of the coefficient and multiply it by the critical t-value to give you confidence interval. You can check out [this book page for the formula](https://www.econometrics-with-r.org/5-2-cifrc.html). The objects from your bootstrapping are not `lm` objects and this function doesn't work. It is not meant for any other estimates.

Comment: All clear, thanks for your answer. I have a following question! Does it is possible (make sense) to estimate confidence intervals of the R2 by using the boot.ci or quantile functions ?